# Ionic 3 app with custom auth

Tags: javascript, authentication, ionic-framework, ionic3

Im trying to build a ionic 3 application, im quite new in this framework.

For now i've just created a basic app that open a web page (an EmonCMS dashboard).

Now i wanted to know if it is possible to implement some sort of authentication on app start up but not via email/pswd but only with 'dashboard name' that will be given to the user.

the process will be:
Ex. A = link to the first dashboard

Open the app
A form will appear asking me the 'dashboard name' 
type 'A'
redirect on the corresponding dashboard if exist

Also i open the webpage in-app with iframe and i know that it's not the best way to do it with ionic, there is any other way?

Thank you all

Comment: I cannot understand what you want exactly. Can you append more explanation or figure for Comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's an authentication, what you want is the user to type where he wants to go, am I right ? If I'm, you could set an `ion-input` on the homepage, and launch a function when he sends the form.

For what you try to do with this iframe, but I never heard about EmonCMS, you could take a look at  [deeplinks](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks/) as it is mentioned here on the [Ionic blog](http://For%20those%20not%20familiar,%20Deeplinking%20makes%20it%20possible%20to%20direct%20a%20user%20to%20content%20hidden%20deep%20in%20a%20native%20app,%20whether%20that%E2%80%99s%20from%20another%20app%20or%20a%20web%20browser.)

> For those not familiar, Deeplinking makes it possible to direct a user to content hidden deep in a native app, whether that’s from another app or a web browser.

Comment: you're right it's not an authentication, and don't want one, simply the user type (if he knows) the 'dashboard name' that corresponds to the link of the web page.

We could, instead of using the 'dashoboard name' method, use the form result to build the url of the web page to redirect the user to his dashboard, but in this case i don't know how to handle a wrong input by the user